# Change encoding to Unicode in .csv exported from Gmail

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, gmail, csv, unicode

I'd like to copy the typed-in addresses from Gmail to Outlook 2021 (Windows 10).

To do this, I'm using the Google Contacts Export to Outlook CSV function and nk2edit.

The problem is that the special characters in the names are crippled.

The only way I've found in Excel to change the encoding is: Data -> Load from Text/CSV and then save as .csv.

The special characters are fixed then, but it's saved as a table and nk2edit can't merge it with Outlook.

I've tried to open it in Notepad, save as "all files," and save it as .csv, but that doesn't fix the issue.

I need to retain this format:
Asko-NĂˇbytek.,,cz,,,,,,,,,,,,sales.eshop@asko.net,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: When saving in Notepad, look to the left of the `Save` button and locate the `Encoding` dropdown. You can selext UTF-8 among a few other standards.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, forgot to try it the other way arround... When I open original .csv in Notepad -> save as .csv with UTF-8 encoding, characters are fixed. However, when I re-open it in Excel / nk2edit, then the characters are crippled again. For some reason, It shows correct characters only when opened in Notepad....

Comment: Only guessing that Excel's default encoding is different. You might do better to search the web for how to change Excel's encoding. It's not something I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to import the .csv file to Outlook desktop and **Map Custom Fields**?

[image]

If you find that the left From field is different from the right To field, please drag the value on the left to the corresponding place on the right.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks good, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.